# Index and match with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, date, indexing, match

I have a database of hourly data for an entire year. I want to find the 98th percentile for NO2 (for example) for each hour for each season (Dec-Jan-Feb, Mar-Apr-May, etc.)

I'm trying to use MATCH and INDEX to find the cells for one hour for one season.

`=INDEX(A1:E8985,MATCH(Z2,(C3:C8985=AA2,AA3,AA13)*(B3:B8985=Z2),0))`

where A1:E8985 is the table area I'm looking in

`Z2` is the hour (1:00), looking in column B, which contains the hours

`AA2,AA3,AA13` are January, February, and December (one season), looking in column C, which contains the months.

Right now, I'm getting an `#N/A` error even though the criteria should be met multiple times. I have made sure that the columns match formats.

Sample of part of the table:

```
Date    Time        Month        NO     NO2

1/1/2016    1:00    January -0.1    0.2
1/1/2016    2:00    January -0.1    0.1
1/1/2016    3:00    January -0.1    0.1
1/1/2016    4:00    January -0.1    0.2
1/1/2016    5:00    January -0.1    0.2
1/1/2016    6:00    January -0.1    0.4
1/1/2016    7:00    January -0.1    0.3
1/1/2016    8:00    January -0.1    0.8
1/1/2016    9:00    January -0.1    0.5
1/1/2016    10:00   January -0.1    0.2
1/1/2016    11:00   January -0.1    1.3
1/1/2016    12:00   January -0.1    0.7
1/1/2016    13:00   January -0.1    0.4
1/1/2016    14:00   January 0   0.7
1/1/2016    15:00   January -0.1    0.5
1/1/2016    16:00   January -0.1    0.4
1/1/2016    17:00   January -0.1    1
1/1/2016    18:00   January -0.1    0.7
1/1/2016    19:00   January -0.1    0.9
1/1/2016    20:00   January 1.6 4.5
1/1/2016    21:00   January 2.8 6
1/1/2016    22:00   January 0.1 1.1
1/1/2016    23:00   January 0.2 1.3
1/2/2016    0:00    January 0.2 1.4
```

Comment: `(C3:C8985=AA2,AA3,AA13)` is wrong syntax for `OR`ing.  Possibly you want: `((C3:C8985=AA2)+(C3:C8985=AA3)+(C3:C8985=AA13))` There could be other issues, but this is clearly one of them.

Comment: Thanks. I actually wanted to do 'and', not 'or'. I've tried with just one input and it still doesn't return anything.

Comment: How can you match Jan AND Feb AND Dec? Each row only contains a single month.

Comment: To elaborate, I would think you would want to test each row to see if ((*theMonth=Jan*) OR (*theMonth=Feb*) OR (*theMonth=Dec*)) AND (*theHour=1:00*).  If that is not the case, then I have misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarize the logic you want, you want the 98 percentile of NO2 where the month is either January, February or December and the value of time is 1:00, then for 2:00 and so on.

If it is so find below the formula applied only to the current data you have provided.

Note that it is an array formula

```
=PERCENTILE.INC(
    IF(C1:C25="January",
        IF(B1:B25=Z2,
            E1:E25,
            ""),
        IF(C1:C25="February",
            IF(B1:B25=Z2,
                E1:E25,
                ""),
            IF(C1:C25="December",
                IF(B1:B25=Z2,
                    E1:E25,
                    ""),
                ""))
    ),0.98)
```